# Adding Custom Attributes to an Office 365 User Mailbox alternative of PowerShell

Tags: outlook, office365, office-interop

Adding,Updating Custom Attributes to Office 365 User Mailbox.I know this can be done through PowerShell but is there any API reference or tool is doing this job for bulk users? I am new to this stuff. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your Identity approach is (Synchronized IDs), your Active Directory onprem is the source of authority, custom attributes could be configured from the on prem application itself or ADSI edit (works but officially not supported by MS!).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-get-started-custom

Azure AD connect is the software you need to install, which controls the attribute flow from AD on prem to Azure AD, You can extend the schema in Azure AD with custom attributes added by your organization or other attributes in Active Directory. To use this feature, select Directory Extension attribute sync on the Optional Features page